# How do I find the lowest or highest point on a UIView being dragged with UIAttachmentBehavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview, uikit-dynamics

Depending on where the `anchorPoint` is with `UIAttachmentBehavior`, the view can be quite rotated, so it's in more of a diamond shape than a square. In these situations, where it's rotated say 90°, how do I find what the lowest or highest point of this `UIView` is (in relation to the window)?

It's easy enough when the `UIView` is a (non-rotated) square, as I can just use `CGRectGetMaxY` (or min) and the x value doesn't matter, and then use `convertPoint`, but with the rotation the x value seems to have a real importance, as if I choose maxX, it will tell me the bottom right's point, while minX will give me the bottom left's.

I just want the lowest point that exists in the `UIView`. How do I get this?

EDIT: Here's some code showing how I'm attempting it currently:

```
CGPoint lowestPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(weakSelf.imageView.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(weakSelf.imageView.bounds));
CGPoint convertedPoint = [weakSelf.imageView convertPoint:lowestPoint toView:nil];
```

The tracking of convertedPoint's y value completely changes depending on what I supply for the x value in `lowestPoint`'s `CGPointMake`.

Answer (score 0):

The view's `frame` is its bounding box. Normally you should be careful about using the `frame` of a transformed view, which is precisely what a rotated-by-UIKit-Dynamics view is. But it does give the info you are after.

Comment: I'm confused how this answers my question.

Comment: Try what exactly? Using the frame of the view? In my second paragraph, which may not be clear, I described that that's what I tried to do, but the x value I supply to the point before it's converted seems to dictate what value I get back for the "lowest point": instead of giving me the lowest point, if I supply maxY and minX, it will track the bottom left corner. If I supply maxY and *maxX* it will track the bottom right corner. I can't seem to get it to track the absolute lowest point. Attached some code to show what I'm doing currently.

Comment: But the code you added shows you using the image view's `bounds`. I'm suggesting that you try using its `frame` instead.

Comment: The frame doesn't appear to change at all, only the bounds of the image view do.